# Is there documentation for the folders in the GAS editor

Tags: google-apps-script, ide

In the left pane of the google apps script editor, there is a button for a new folder.  I have not been able to find out what one can do with this.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean please? Like a screenshot

Comment: I'm guessing that you are using the Google Apps Sidebar toggle Chrome extension.  [Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-apps-sidebar-toggl/ohpabiillaflohfmoelpklnloimplacc) The "New Folder" button groups files into folders.  That is done in the browser.  It's not a native capability of the Apps Script editor.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Apps Script Editor doesn't include folders as a built-in function, but you could use Google Drive folders to organize files, including  Google Apps Script project files but not the internal .gs and .html files.

Comment: Since this is a perfectly accurate answer I will add to it by saying that this is a feature that is added by some chrome extensions. One that comes to mind and that I use is AppsScript Color. When you click "New Folder" you can create a folder and then move the .gs files into those folders to organize your script by using drag and drop. This is only based locally and is not reliable as sometimes files can jump out of those folders. If you try to edit your code somewhere where you do not have this chrome extension, you will not see the folders.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the two comments:  the pane labeled "New Folder" was put there by the extension, AppsScript Color, which I tried at one time.